# How to render Vue Component dynamically with render()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

In **Vuejs 3** I want to use the `render()` function to create a VNode, passing it a Vue `Component`. This component varies depending on the current route.

In `vite.js` I haven't found a way to import a component dynamically inside my `ViewComponent` computed function.

With webpack I could normally use `` return require(`./pages/${matchingPage}.vue`).default ``, but this is not possible with `vitejs` as I will get a `Require is not a function` error.

So I tried `` return import(`./pages/${matchingPage}.vue`) `` but it returns a `Promise`, not a `Component`

```
//main.js

import {createApp, h} from 'vue'
import routes from './routes'

const SimpleRouterApp = {
  data: () => ({
    currentRoute: window.location.pathname
  }),

  computed: {
    ViewComponent () {
      const matchingPage = routes[this.currentRoute] || '404'
      return import(`./pages/${matchingPage}.vue`)
    }
  },

  render () {
    return h(this.ViewComponent)
  },

  created () {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
      this.currentRoute = window.location.pathname
    })
  }
}

createApp(SimpleRouterApp).mount('#app')
```

What other ways can I try so `render()` can return a `Component` dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [async-components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#async-components) :

```
import {createApp, h,defineAsyncComponent} from 'vue'
....
  

  render () {
  const matchingPage = routes[this.currentRoute] || '404'
    const ViewComponent= defineAsyncComponent(
      () =>import(`./pages/${matchingPage}.vue`)
   
   )
    return h(ViewComponent)
  },
```